# Send query parameters from API Gateway to a Step Functions Choice

Tags: aws-api-gateway, aws-step-functions

I have an AWS Step Function called trough API Gateway with the following Choice:

```
"Router": {
        "Type": "Choice",
        "Choices": [
          {
            "Variable": "$.deviceType",
            "StringEquals": "queclink-gl501mg",
            "Next": "Queclink GL501MG Uplink"
          },
          {
            "Variable": "$.deviceType",
            "StringEquals": "queclink-gl502mg",
            "Next": "Queclink GL502MG Uplink"
          },
          {
            "Variable": "$.deviceType",
            "StringEquals": "queclink-gl505",
            "Next": "Queclink GL505 Uplink"
          },
          {
            "Variable": "$.deviceType",
            "StringEquals": "tive",
            "Next": "Tive"
          },
          {
            "Variable": "$.deviceType", // Something like $.queryparams.deviceType ?
            "StringEquals": "kkmKG01",
            "Next": "KkmKG01"
          }
        ],
        "Default": "Error"
      },
```

The last option (kkmKG01) doesn't match because the device can't send a deviceType in it's payload.
What I want to do is to specify the deviceType in a query param since I can configure the url my device calls.

I added a query param in both the Method Request and Integration Request in API Gateway:
[image: My Integration request query param]

But I don't know how to check the deviceType from the query param instead on the deviceType from the payload in my Step Function.

Comment: What HTTP method are you using to integrate your API method with the step function?

Comment: I call my endpoint with a POST method

Comment: As per the AWS docs, All step functions API actions use the HTTP `POST` method. And the `StartExecution` API Request accepts the inputs as a json payload, so i don't think you can use GET parameters as input to StartExecution Requests parameter.

Comment: Instead you can pass the parameters into request body and post it to step function.